# xcode does't generate .h file for swift framework project?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I created a framework writting on pure swift ,
but I cant find any .h file of public class . shouldn't Xcode generate .h file automaticly?

here is project structure

```
- ProjectName  
  -- ProjectName.h  
  -- publicClass.swift
```

the final projectname.framework  does not contails the publicClass.h ,neither any "publicClass" string

Xcode Version 13.1 (13A1030d)

I searched the internet but got little about this problem

Comment: Swift doesn’t use header files, you just get one .swift file

Comment: @jmsapps  I write this framework  for other oc/c project. so i need .h file

Answer (score 0):

**After practice.**

When import your framework in a project, import your framework in
a swift file, long press `command` then click your framework name in the file, Xcode will create a public interface file automatically, and you will see all your public classes functions.

Below is not a right answer, please ignore it.

[Headers png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ms6c.png)

In `TARGETS`, select your framework, then in `Build Phases`, there is a `Headers` section, you could put your public swift file under `Public`, then command + B, in your framework folder, headers file, you will see.

Comment: Not a good right answer

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't use header files, you only get .swift files. If you want header file you have to use Objective-C.